# How to execute recursively a program on every files contained in directory with find

Tags: files, find, c, arguments, recursive

I wrote an executable that I want to execute on all the files contained in a directory.

This is what the program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    char argNormaux[4096] = {0};
    char argNeg[4096] = {0};
    char argEt[4096] = {0};
    int nbArgsNormaux = 0;
    if (argc > 2){
        for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++){
            const char *arg = argv[i];
            if (strstr(argv[i],"et") != NULL){
                strcat(argEt, argv[i]);
            }
            else if (strstr(argv[i], "!") != NULL){
                strcat(argNeg, argv[i]);
            }
            else {
                strcat(argNormaux, argv[i]);
                nbArgsNormaux++;
            }
        }
        const char *path = argv[1];
        char buf[4096];
        int rc;
        rc = listxattr(path, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (rc < 0){
            perror("listxattr");
        }
        else {
            if (strlen(buf) == 0){
                printf("No tag.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            int tagsNormauxCheck = 0;
            int tagsNegCheck = 0;
            char *token = buf;
            while(*token){
                char tagBuf[4096];
                if (strlen(token) == 2){
                    if (strcmp(token, "\0\0\0")) break;
                }
                rc = getxattr(path, token, &tagBuf, sizeof(tagBuf));
                if (rc < 0){
                    perror("getxattr");
                }
                else {
                    if (strstr(argNormaux, tagBuf) != NULL) {
                        tagsNormauxCheck++;
                    }
                    if (strstr(argNeg, tagBuf) != NULL) {
                        tagsNegCheck = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                memset(&tagBuf, 0, sizeof(tagBuf));
                token = strchr(token, '\0');
                token++;
            }
            if (tagsNormauxCheck == nbArgsNormaux && tagsNegCheck == 0){
                printf("Le fichier %s possède la combinaison des tags donnés.", path);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Pas assez d'arguments.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the command line I'm trying to use :

`find . -type f -exec ./logic testDir/ essai '{}' \;`

What I'm expecting is to have the `logic` executable applied on every files in that `testDir`, but what it does is that it applies it directly on `testDir` for each file there is in that dir, which is not what I want...  I've been trying to make it work for days, it's just annoying, `logic` work perfectly fine when applied on a single file. So I don't know what should I do to achieve what I want. The file argument on which `logic` is applied doesn't change with that command.

EDIT : Adding more context on what I want to achieve, the purpose of `logic` and how I want it to work.

`logic` is a program that shows if a file have the combinaiton of the extended arguments passed to `logic`. One example of execution of `logic` alone is : `logic testfile.txt programming class university \!art`. So basically: tell me if `testfile.txt` has the combination of tags `programming and class and university and not art`.

Now let's say I have a directory such as :

```
testDir/
├── dir2
│   ├── dir2file1.txt
│   ├── dir2file2.txt
│   └── dir2file3.txt
├── file1.txt
├── file2.txt
├── file3.txt
└── file4.txt

1 directory, 7 files
```

I want `logic` to be executed on each file present in that directory tree. (folders excluded)

So basically, my problem here is that the file argument passed to `logic` when using `find` isn't changing. It will stay `testDir/`, but I'd like it to be `testDir/file1.txt`, then `testDir/file2`, until it reaches `dir2file3.txt`.

Anyway to make it work please?

Thanks.

Comment: so everything inside the `testDir` should be an input for your `logic` program?

Comment: I added more information on what I want to achieve. I do want to pass it multiple arguments like I showed in the edit, the first one is the file it needs to check, the other ones are tags. Sorry, the recommended question didn't help :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if you want the file path to be the *first* argument to your program:

```
find testDir -type f -exec ./logic {} essai \;
```

This will search the directory `testDir` (as well as any subdirectory of `testDir`) for regular files, and for each found file, it will call your program with the pathname of the file as the first argument (and with `essai` as the second argument).

The difference between this and your own command,

```
find . -type f -exec ./logic testDir/ essai '{}' \;
```

is that

1. The pathname of the found file is passed as the *last* command line argument,
2. The first argument is always `testdir/`,
3. You search the *current* directory (and its subdirectories).

Answer (score 0):

This can do what you are looking for -

`find testDir/ -type f | awk '{system("./logic "$1" -your_args_here")}'`